# Updating Network Solutions Virtual Private Server

Tags: linux, vps, redhat, update

Just got a VPS from Network Solutions, it's got Red Hat 4, PHP 5.16, Java 1.4, no Yum and a whole bunch of packages I'd expect to have from a fresh install.

Anyway, obviously I sound like a spoiled Ubunutoligist, but do I seriously have to manually update all this stuff, is there a shortcut, I'm used to Fedora, so I'm not sure what the differences are between using Yum in Redhat and Fedora.

Should I just demand that Network Solutions give me a server that's not 4 years old or is there a way to update this thing that won't take all week?

Answer (score 1):

I'm more used to Ubuntu (and also to systems which come with package management tools installed) but assuming rpm is installed, could you not just install the Yum rpm from a package then use it to upgrade the rest of the system?  If rpm's not installed, you could use alien on a local machine to convert the package to a tgz then install that.

Comment: Yeah, it's got RPM installed, I just can't find the YUM RPM for this distro and I don't have a copy of REHL (I think it costs like 80 buck) However, I just did a Plesk update (after calling Network Solutions and finding out they're still without a method for actually updating the OS) Now I seem to be installing a whole bunch of Fedora Core 6 RPMs.  I guess I'll try getting yum for Fedora Core 6 and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the "up2date" command.  "yum" is an RHEL5-ism.

I'm assuming you mean RHEL4, not Red Hat 4.  If it's RH 4, demand a distro that's been supported in the last 10 years :)

Comment: Yeah it's REHL4, Red Hat 4 would be pretty.  up2date is an old Red Hat command though isn't it?   Either way, neither Yum nor up2date is installed. Do you by chance know if there's anything like archives.fedoraproject.org for REHL?

Comment: I'd start asking the company for a recent OS in your brand new system.  If it doesn't work, why not look at another company?  I use Linode and have been pretty happy with them.